# How can I install the older gnome control center in 11.10?

Tags: gnome, 11.10

Is there a way to install the control center used in Ubuntu 11.04 on 11.10. Now i have the options to change things under System Settings but i would like to have the old "control center" back.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't easily possible because of 11.10's move to GNOME 3. (It's far easier just to stay with 11.04, if that's what you want!)

Comment: that's a bit to late.. already upgrade all systems to 11.10 :) Thanks for the answer, i already had a feeling that it wasn't possible but it never hurts to ask... ask ubuntu :)

Answer (score -1):

Use the repo. Open a terminal, and enter this:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/natty/gnome-control-center

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: sorry my bad ... i added an image to my question so you can see what i want to have back. I already tried to install gnome-control-center but i got the message that it's already installed on the system. And i'm using Ubuntu 11.10 :)

Comment: i just upped a vote but it seems some else is responsible for the down vote... if i undo my vote it will be back at -1

Comment: Ok, changed my answer. But in my opinion everyone who is using ubuntu should can open a terminal.

Comment: Downvoted simply because this does not work in 11.10

Comment: ... but all you have stated is to install gnome-control-center from the 11.10 repositories - the OP has asked how to install the 11.04 version.

Comment: its also included in oneiric repo: http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/oneiric/gnome-control-center